# php foreach value loop of variables in file.php instead of array

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I'm trying to find a way to create a foreach loop where I can echo all values, which I can do in an array, but the issue is (as far as I know) I cannot echo them like variables with their name.

Example right now:

```
<?php
$stuff = array(
foo => "<a href=\"/foo\">foo</a>",
bar => "<a href=\"/bar\">bar</a>",
thing => "Thing",
);
?>

<?php
foreach($stuff as $val) {
    print '<li>' . $val . '</li>';
}
?>
```

My issue is, I can't just echo one of these by name anywhere like `<?php echo $foo; ?>` like if they were stored as variables. From what I can tell, I could only echo them by their number like `<?php echo $stuff[1]; ?>`

What I want to do is store variables in a file like file.php and still be able to do a foreach loop like above.

Example:

```
<?php
$foo = "<a href="/foo">foo</a>";
$bar = "<a href="/bar">bar</a>";
$thing = "Thing";
?>
```

Pseudo code of what I want:

```
<?php
foreach(var in /path/to/file.php as $value) {
    print '<li>' . $value . '</li>';
}
?>
```

How can I foreach loop through variables in an included file.php?

Comment: `echo $stuff['foo'];` maybe?

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much.. I had no idea it was just a matter of adding single quotation marks. Could you reply with that as an answer so I can select it as correct?

Comment: your first version is FAR easier to maintain/use. it's just an array. your second version would litter your varaible space with random var names and they cannot be foreached(), since they're NOT an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to use the array.  You can `foreach()` over it and also access the items directly:

```
echo $stuff['foo'];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you include a file in php it is helpful to think of it as simply copy pasting the contents of that file directly into your script where you are making the include.

because you have declared the array as

```
$stuff
```

I would recommend keeping them in array form. Then, you should be able to access its keys in the following manner.

```
echo $stuff['foo'];
echo $stuff['bar'];
echo $stuff['thing'];
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can also try something like this using a variable variable (http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
$foo = 'hi';
$bar = 'you';
$thing = 'all';

$stuff = array(
    'foo' => "<a href=\"/foo\">foo</a>",
    'bar' => "<a href=\"/bar\">bar</a>",
    'thing' => "Thing",
);

foreach($stuff as $key => $value) {
    print '<li>' . $$key . '</li>'; //Note the double dollar $$
}
```

Result:

```
hi
you
all
```